# Accessing object behind bindingsource

Tags: vb.net, listbox, user-controls, bindingsource

I am creating a simple card sorting application. Users should be able to create list boxes and add/remove/move items among them.
I've got 3 classes like CardsCollection > Cards > Card
I also created a user control with a label and a listbox.
When the user creates a new sort group by dragging an item from another listbox, a new Cards object is created within the CardsCollection, a bindingsource linked to that, and a new user control (CardsControl) with a listbox bound to this bindingsource:

```
 Private Sub flPanel_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles flPanel.DragDrop

        Dim strtitle = InputBox("Create new sort group", "Enter group title", "New group")

        If Not strtitle = "" Then

            Dim cc As New CardsControl
            cc.CardsTitle.Text = strtitle
            Dim ls As ListBox = cc.lsCards

            Dim cards As New cards
            Dim card As card = lsCards.SelectedItem
            Dim bs As New BindingSource
            bs.DataSource = cards
            AllCards.cards.Remove(card)
            cards.cards.Add(card)
            flPanel.Controls.Add(cc)

            ls.DataSource = bs
            ls.DataSource = cards.cards
            ls.DisplayMember = "title"

        End If

    End Sub
```

As the user controls are created realtime, I cannot add their code to the forms, so I need to manage everything inside the user control.

I have the following code in my control:

```
Public Class CardsControl
    Private Sub lsCards_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles lsCards.DragDrop
        Dim card As card = e.Data.GetData(GetType(card))
        lsCards.Items.Add(card) 'this doesn't work, because the list is data bound
    End Sub

    Private Sub lsCards_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles lsCards.DragOver

        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(card)) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I marked the code with a comment. Here something is wrong, the execution stops without error message, and I return to the main screen.
After some searching, I found that I cannot add an item to a data bound listbox. So, my question is, how can I reach the cards object that is behind the listbox's data source, from within the user control?

Update:
Thank you, @LarsTech !
Based on your comment, I updated my code and now I can use data source objects. I had to move the 2nd "cards" object to the DataMember property of the BindingSource.
The relevant lines are:

```
    bs.DataSource = cards
    bs.DataMember = "cards"
    ls.DataSource = bs
    ls.DisplayMember = "title"
```

Comment: You didn't document what `cards.cards` is, but you would have to cast the DataSource to that, and add the item to that collection.

Comment: Well, I know it's confusing. I like having a parent object on top of my collections. The 2nd cards is a Bindinglist (of card) object, the first is just a parent for this. This is an auto-generated class based on an xml document. But your comment indeed gave a hint, and found that my datasource was not properly configured. So, thank you.